# Where can I find logs logged by Fabric's Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I've embedded Fabric's Answers and Crashlytics in my iOS app, and also implemented the Crashlytics logger (CLS_LOG).
But I could not find (or understand) in their documentation where can I find the logs logged by that logger. 
Is it only sent in a case of a crash? Is it part from the crash report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the docs and found the below, you can see these logs associated with your crash report. Please look it in your Fabric Dashboard. Moreover this helps you to find the problem of the crash.

To find out where this log file resides you can search all the directories of your app [excluding main bundle].

> It’s often useful to have some context recorded about the events leading up to a crash. Crashlytics provides logging facilities to make this easy. These messages are associated with your crash data and are visible in the Fabric dashboard if you look at the specific crash.

Comment: After how much time should a log message appear in the Fabric Dashboard?

Answer (score 16):

It's a bit old question but maybe it helps. 
You can find logs in this order;

1. Enter into details of the crash by clicking on the crash in the list.
2. In the right bottom you will see version information. Click on which version you want to see logs from.
3. In the opened panel you will see a log switch button. Be sure that it is open.
4. When you open logs from switch button you will see logs and you will be able to download logs.
   I hope it helps.